# Mapping complex JSON model in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

I can get response in JSON, but it seems like it cannot be mapped into mutArray.

```
    BaseHttpRequest.shareInstance.myGET(detailURL, parameters: kid) { (response) in

        var mutArray = Array <KingdomDetail> ()

        if response is Array <JSON> {

            for jsonObj in response as! Array<JSON> {

                if let kingdomDetailList = KingdomDetail(json: jsonObj) {
                    mutArray.append(kingdomDetailList)
                } else {
                    print("nothing")
                }
            }
        }
        success(success: mutArray)
    }
```

Comment: What response/behavior/error are you seeing?

Comment: oh I mean func will return the (response), but when I use break point to po mutArray, it is just return 0 value

Comment: Is the if statement executing?

Comment: which if you mean? if let or if response?

Comment: and I use Gloss with AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#non-optional-getter). If so, you can use `arrayValue` to produce an array of JSON with an empty array as a fallback value.

```
for kingdomDetailList in response.arrayValue.flatMap({ KingdomDetail(json: $0) })  {
    mutArray.append(kingdomDetailList)
}
```

You might also want to make sure that your JSON mapping is correct. It is possible this array is wrapped in a keyed value. In which case you'll need to reference it when sending it to your initializer.

```
response["kingdom_detail_list"].arrayValue ...
```